# Operation returned an invalid status 'Bad Request' during azure cli operation

Tags: bash, azure, terraform, azure-cli, azure-rm

**Objective:** Checking whether a resource group exist in given subscription on Azure with shell script (azure cli command) (runs as part of terraform deployment)

**Context**: This piece of code runs on a docker based image (Ubuntu). The below is part of my CI pipeline

**Code I use:**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "export ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID=${subscriptionid}" >> $BASH_ENV
source $BASH_ENV
printenv
apk add gcc musl-dev python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev cargo make
apk add py3-pip
pip install azure-cli
az login --service-principal -u $ARM_CLIENT_ID -p $ARM_CLIENT_SECRET --tenant $ARM_TENANT_ID
az account set -s $ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID
if [$(az group exists --name *orp*)]; then
    az group create --name test --location westeurope
fi
terraform -chdir=Terraform init -input=false -backend-config="resource_group_name=${TF_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME}" \
-backend-config="storage_account_name=${TF_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}" \
-backend-config="container_name=<<pipeline.parameters.clientcode>>" \
-backend-config="key=<<pipeline.parameters.environment>>/${TF_KEY_NAME}"
```

**Error I get:**

```
./scripts/check.sh: line 10: []: not found
```

Can some one suggest what wrong with this ?

I tried with below, then also same error saying bad request.

```
if [$(az group exists --name *orp*) = false ]; then
    az group create --name test --location eastus
fi
```

I am trying to use wildcard to search for resource groups that may be available in subscritpion. is this * xxx * is correct pattern to search ?

Comment: Add a space between `[` and `$`

Comment: @Inian its still same error i get..

Comment: Could you please try to add a space between `) ] `at this line last `[$(az group exists --name *orp*)]` as well

Comment: hi @AjayKumarGhose  I did as you suggested but I am getting this one `ERROR: Operation returned an invalid status 'Bad Request`

Comment: Have you given execute access to that file

Comment: Could you please refer this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458034/azure-cli-how-to-check-if-a-resource-exists)